# xlsx sent in email shows as .zip

Tags: excel, zip

Before anyone says it, yes I could just get the .xlsx resent but that's no fun.

I've been sent an email with an attachment that is meant to be a .xlxs (from the subject line) but is attached as a zip with a different filename.

I've unzipped the file and within it is another folder of the same name.

so the structure looks like this.

12345.zip

- 12345

  - _rels
  - customXML
  - docProps
  - xl
  - [Content_Types].xml

So I renamed the .zip .xlsx, didn't work.

So I zipped the folder 12345 and changed the .zip to 12345.xlsx - didnt work.

I compared this to a test .xlsx, unzipped it and saw that there is no customXML folder (also examples in google don't have this folder). So i tried two things, delete the folder and copy out the files into 12345 and also just delete the folder (by this point I'm curious what excel can recover)....and rezip and reappend.

So where am I going wrong? customXML is referenced in another .xml so I'm pretty sure its meant to be there.

is it an office 365 conversion, a  compression issue when its re-zipped and then appended?

Thanks,

Comment: Its difficult to guess what the problem is.  What happens when you try to open the original file after adding the .zip extension?

Comment: Create an empty Excel file and unzip it. Replace the folders (_rels, xl,...) with the folders from the email file. Rezip and try to open.

Comment: When you write extracting the archive puts everything in a folder 12345 is that because that folder is defined in the ZIP file or because you chose to extract to that folder? Note that xl, _rels, [Content_Types].xml need to be on the top level of the ZIP/XLSX file, not inside a subfolder.

Comment: @TimWilliams excel tries to recover and then says its corrupted

Comment: @PaulB. the folder is defined within the zip. I ignore that first folder

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "I ignore that first folder". [Content_Types].xml etc. need to be direct member of the ZIP/XLSX file otherwise Excel won't recognize the file.

Comment: @paul there was an additional file between the zip and the other folders, i.e it should have been:

12345.zip
- _rels
-  customXML
- docProps
- xl
- [Content_Types].xml

Comment: turns out file was corrupted anyway